# regular expression to match numbers if a character is not a leading and trailing character

Tags: regex

I need to match numbers as long as it is not found between `{` and `}`.

Examples:

```
{1}  - should not match  
1 - should match
2 - should match
{91} - should not match
3 - match
0 - match
{1212} - should not match
```

I wrote this `(?!{)[\d](?!})`

and it correctly matches those numbers outside `{` and `}` however when there is more than 1 digit in `{}` such as `{123}`, then it matches `12` excluding the last digit.

Comment: You need the "greedy" operator for the digit part.

Comment: Looking at the alerady posted answers it is clear that you should explain in more detail the context of your question. Are those numbers (like in your example) all alone on a new line one by one? Are they only surrounded by `{}` or by nothing at all? Or could there be other characters too?

Comment: Also: can the {} be nested? is `13}` valid?

Comment: how about just ^\d+$ ? It will do exactly what you need for the inputs you specified.

Comment: @LordOfThePigs Good catch! Most posters here did not see this easy way out. This kinda proves that there is more to the problem than the OP reveales in his examples =)

Answer (score 3):

You'd better go with:

```
\d+(?![^{]*})
```

***Explanations:***

```
\d+           # Any digits
(?![^{]*})    # Negative lookahead - demonstrating to not within curly braces
```

**[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/tC9iL3)**

Comment: Could you elaborate on how the negative lookahead works with `[^{]*`?

Comment: @Neftas Lookahead assertion isn't forced to have fixed width and so we can use quantifiers. That said, `(?![^{]*}) ` alone, will look for any position not within brackets.

Comment: So basically you're looking for a digit of length one or longer, if it finds that, the regex then continues to look for another opening curly brace `{`, and starts to backtrack to see if it can find a closing brace `}` adjacent to the digits. If it doesn't, it's a match, if it does, it's not. Very ingenious, thanks! :)

Comment: @Neftas Looking for opening curly brace `{` isn't started at a specific position. Lookahead - as being a lookaround - returns true whether it matches the positions. So it's not just the above regex I wrote!! You can achieve the same results with `(?![^{]*})\d+` too. You're welcome!

Comment: Wow! +10! Your explanation just opened my eyes to a whole new dimension of lookahead. It really is more than `is my expression followed by this expression`. Looking at your solution makes me wonder why there is lookbehind at all ;)

Comment: @SebastianH Remmeber the words "Immediate" and "Strict" when it comes to using look arounds. As my answer you may think `(?!my)regex` will match word **regex** not followed by **my** too, but that's not, as **myregex** will be a match. Here lookahead is meaningless because we strictly need an immediate matching in which **regex** is not followed by **my** - now we know lookbehinds are born `(?<!my)regex`. However as OP asked there is no strictness in matching digits here and then we can use lookahead.

Comment: It will fail `91}` case, though OP doesn't have such sample.

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Because it's not included at all!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to also **exclude** numbers having curly bracket on only one side, like `{123`, `123}`, then you can use the following regex (negative lookbehind and negative lookahead are used):

```
(?<![{\d])\d+(?![}\d])
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/jJRLJaJE0_fXbucR)

If you want to **include** numbers having curly bracket on only one side, you can use **or** condition:

```
(?<![{\d])\d+(?![}\d])|(?<={)\d+(?![}\d])|(?<![{\d])\d+(?=})
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EJbINK_VpKK5iXJe)

Comment: Good thinking beyond the given examples =)

Answer (score 2):

**(I used javascript in this example)**

This simple regex should show exactly what you don't want, so just check if it does not match this regex:

```
var strings = ['{1}', '1', '2', '{{91}', '3', '0', '{1212}'];
strings.map(function (str) {
    return !str.match(/(\{\d+\})/); 
}); // returns [false, true, true, false, true, true, false]
```

Comment: I like this solution, because it does not require mind-boggling regexp statments for a seemingly trivial task. But this strongly depends on the context of the question if this solution is viable (see my comment on the question). Btw. you have written it in JS, but something like this is possible in every language. The basic concept is to transfer logic from the regex to the programming language - which often is a good idea :)

Answer (score 1):

The following regexs will do that:

`^(?!={)(\d+)(?!=})$`    or    `^(?!{)(\d+)(?!})$`

```
{1}
1          Match
2          Match
{91}
3          Match
0          Match
{1212}
```

### Demo

Comment: I think the regexp should be `^(?!{)(\d+)(?!})$` (the `=` are superfluous). This only works with the `^$` anchors in place.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to regexp, simple is beautiful

```
^\d+$
```

No lookaheads or other complicated constructs. It's probably the simplest regexp that yields correct results for the sample inputs you provided.

Answer (score 0):

you should use this :

```
^(?!\{)(\d+)(?!\})$
```

it's your regex, but I added `\` to escape `{` and a group `(\d+)` to get the data you want ;)

Comment: Wrong! This will match the `9` in `{91}`.

Comment: true but the pattern get a `matches()` rejected so it's not a problem.
But change it to `^(?!\{)(\d+)(?!\})$` and you won't get this problem

Comment: Correct now. But its depending on the `^$` anchors now. Lets see if the questioner will add further context.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this"

```
^(?!{)\d+(?!=})$
```

Comment: I wonder why everyone is using the superfluous `=` in negative lookarounds :) The syntax is `(?=_)` for positive lookahead and `(?!_)` for negative lookahead (where `_` is my placeholder for the regex inside). Analogous for lookbehinds.